# Shimano TOURNEY FC-TY301 crank arm material

Tags: crankset

I have spent ~30 minutes searching for a clue, maybe I'm getting old and dull...
Are the FC-TY301 crank arms made of steel or aluminium alloy?

Comment: I didn't find a definitive answer either, but the listing on walmart.com says it's aluminum. That would be my guess looking at pictures. The chainrings appear to be steel.

Comment: Yes, that was my guess as well looking at the pictures. Steel is good, be it frames or chainrings :-)

Comment: Steel cranks usually have rather thin arms.

Answer (score 2):

The crank-arms are aluminium as of any Shimano cranks but the chain-rings in this case are steel. The axle is always steel.

If you have a unit at hand, it's easy to check with a magnet.

(Anyway, a magnet may be a useful item also in shop for a discrete test of a component or a metal frame for material.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that all Shimano cranks have alloy arms.